# Check for Anti-Virus Artifacting with cksum

Tags: diff, checksum, antivirus

I'm looking for a good way to see if Avira Anti-virus ([www.avira.com](http://www.avira.com)) is leaving any traces behind after a scan. I am working in an environment where it is critical that nothing be modified, and that the box is disconnected from the network as per user specifications. The concept was to use cksum to monitor all files on a box, then pipe output to a text file, and diff the pre- and post-Avira cksums.

I have tried:

```
$ find . | xargs cksum | sort > cksum_A.txt
```

And

```
$ find . \! -type p -exec cksum {} \; > cksum_A.txt
```

I deleted all temporary and permanent instances of the cksum_A.txt and cksum_B.txt from both files, as it would certainly be used as a difference.

In multiple cases **without** running the anti-virus in-between, './.local/share/gvfs-metadata...' and './.gconf/apps/nautilus...' were found to have been modified according to diff.

The question is, is there a better way to identify artifacting on a bit-level? Or just disregard these files and move on?

Thanks!

Mason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to run from single-user mode, or at least switch off the GUI, to run the scan, as GUI applications and daemons may well write files in between.

Comment: Ah, that's a very good point - I'll give that a try shortly and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, so running in not single user mode [Couldn't activate writing after dropping to root shell even after remounting], but by entering text terminal mode, all issues were resolved. However, I couldn't find a good way to silence cksum [-S is only used with -c {--check}]. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MasonWinsauer I'm not sure what you want to silence - is cksum reporting errors? I guess you could restrict the find to `-type f` to only do the ordinary files, and do something to exclude /proc and /sys as well.

Comment: Just to keep any potential for modifying temp files to a minimum. Oh well, thanks guys!